# What could be Wordpress CPU requirements compared to its RAM requirements?

Tags: vps, hardware, wordpress

Im not asking how much RAM/CPU my website(s) will need to run, but if it is possible to determine a relation between CPU and RAM. Is there a relation? When I want more CPU and when I want more RAM to assure a smooth run of my website?

**edit**: Im more interested in relation between required CPU and RAM and what processes (plug-ins in my case) affect more on CPU and what other more on the RAM. For example, would make sense to have a `2,5GHz Hexa-Core` with `2 GB RAM`? Or an app requiring such CPU would more likely need more RAM aswell? Similarly, would make sense to have a `Single Core` loaded with `16 GB RAM`?

Comment: Wordpress run on PHP. PHP is both CPU and RAM hungry. The ratio depends on plugins, user behaviour, and how much caching you do. Note that page caching on your web server, for anonymous user traffic, is probably the #1 thing you can do to reduce load. You really just need to either load test or watch the server resources and see which comes close to limits and increase it. This is usually not difficult to increase when using virtualisation.

Comment: Regarding your edit, my comment above still stands. 6 cores / 2GB RAM and 1 core / 16GB RAM seem to be extremes. How about starting with 2-4 cores and 4-8GB RAM. If you're on a cloud platform start small and change VM size / scaling horizontally as required.

Comment: @Tim extremes in my example are possible scenarios?

Comment: I assume you're saying those are the two options you have for Virtual Machines. If I had to choose one, I'd benchmark my server first. If you can't benchmark your server you're probably in over your head. Really though I'd try for a better balance of resources instead of high ram / low cpu or low ram / high cpu.

Comment: I agree with Tim, you must benchmark to know what your ratio is, and what you need, For example I run at home a wordpress's site, but on a raspberry pi.. but low on traffic too.

Comment: @Tim neither one is an option, my question is about what between CPU and RAM is more affected by what type of action/situation on a WP installation.

Comment: There is no generic answer to your question sorry. Read my first reply.